# Array of Array Node js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm doing an Api call to receive some data about the users i'm following.
And for the moment i receive something like that [[{obj1},{obj2}],[{obj3}]] and I want something like this [{obj1},{obj2},{obj3}]. Because one user can have more than one object.

```
 getDashboard = function (req, res) {
  User.findById(req.params.id, function (err, user) {
        if (!user) {
            res.send(404, 'User not found');
        }
        else {
            var a = user.following;
            var promises = a.map(function(current_value) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            Receta.find({"user_id":current_value._id}, function (err, recetas) {
            if(!err) {              
                    resolve(recetas);
            } else {
                    reject(err);
                    }
            });
            });
            });

            Promise.all(promises).then(function(allData) {
                var proms = allData.map(function(value){
                    return value 
                    });
                res.send(proms);
            }).catch(function(error) {
                res.send(error);
            });
        }
  });
};
```

Comment: If one user can have more than one object, the format you want won't be able to represent it.

Comment: What is "*`allData.map(function(value){
                    return value 
                    })`*" supposed to do?

Comment: You want to **flatten** the array. Google that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ES6 [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```js
 var data = [["one", "two"],["three"],["four","five"]];
 result = [].concat(...data);
 console.log(result);
```

Alternative in ES5 you could use reduce :

```js
var data = [["one", "two"],["three"],["four","five"]];
var result = data.reduce(function(prev,curv){
    return prev.concat(curv)
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** *I'm not quite sure this is what the question was asking, but this was my interpretation*

So you want to flatten out an array? Let's first build a function that takes a nested array and flattens it out a single level, like so:

```
function flatten(arr){
    var result = [];
    arr.forEach(element => (
        result = result.concat(element);
    ));
    return result;
}
```

Now, what if we have a 3D array, like `[[["hi"]]]`. Then, we need to flatten it multiple times. In fact, we can do this recursively.

Each time, we can check if it's an array using `Array.isArray()`, and if it is, flatten it before appending. We can program this recursively.

```
function flatten(arr){
    var result = [];
    arr.forEach(element => (
        result = result.concat(Array.isArray(element) ? flatten(element) : element)
    ));
    return result;
}
```

and that is our final answer. With that second function, we can see that `flatten(["hi", ["there"]])` works.

Comment: i mean now i have something like this [["one", "two"],["three"]] and i want this ["one", "two", "three"]

Comment: Yep, then this answer is for you :)